# Internet Connection Changed Broadcast Receiver is not executing when app is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need a Broadcast Receiver name "NetworkReciver.java" that should execute when Internet is Connected or Disconnected. But it is not executing when app is closed or when app is not running.

**API 23 and Above**

NetworkReciver executes only when app is running.

I want a reciever to monitor the Internet Connection even when the app is closed.

Manifest permissions

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

In Activity

```
  this.registerReceiver(mYBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
    "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
```

NetworkReciever.java:

```
 public class NetworkReciever extends BroadcastReceiver 
 {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
     {
            Log.i("TAG", "Network REceiver Connection Chnaged");
     }
}
```

Comment: register your receiver in manifest

Comment: if you register receiver programmatically, it will be unregistered withing context lifecycle.